# Sumifs with OR condition on 2nd criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, excel-2021

I am trying to SUMIFs total product quantity based on product's SKU and Status.
To keep track of my inventory, I used SUMIFs function to sum the products SKUs and their quantities. But i also wish to only deduct the products based on the status (Ordered/Shipped)

Currently I am using `=SUMIFS(SalesTable[Quantity];SalesTable[SKU];[@[Stocks SKU]];SalesTable[Status];"Ordered")`

I also tried:
`SUMIFS(SalesTable[Quantity];SalesTable[SKU];[@[Stocks SKU]];SalesTable[Status];OR("Ordered";"Shipped"))`

`SUMIFS(SalesTable[Quantity];SalesTable[SKU];[@[StocksSKU]];SalesTable[Status];"Ordered";SalesTable[Status];"Shipped")`

How do I add Shipped as the criteria as well? I tried adding it as the 3rd criteria but it doesnt work.

Comment: To get the value of my closing inventory, i was thinking of using
Opening Inventory - sumifs(quantity, product sku, inventory sku, status, ordered/shipped)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is easier to help you if you add some sample data and expected output to your question. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SalesTable[Quantity]*
        (SalesTable[SKU]=[@[Stocks SKU]]) *
        ((SalesTable[Status]="Ordered") + (SalesTable[Status]="Shipped"))
)
```

`*` --> AND-condition

`+` --> OR-condition

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To create OR criteria with SUMIFS, place the criteria in an array, then wrap the whole thing in the SUM function. For example:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(SalesTable[Quantity];SalesTable[SKU];[@[Stocks SKU]];SalesTable[Status];{"Ordered";"Shipped"}))
```